# Expected sojourn time for a pinned brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The problem I am trying to solve is the following:

What is the expected time the Wiener process $W_{t}$ stays above t-axis for $t\in [0;1]$ if we know that $W_{1}=a$?

I suppose that this is a well known problem, but I can't find a useful reference. If there is no closed form solution for this problem but maybe there are some approximations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pinned Brownian motion $W^a_t$ can be expressed in terms of usual Brownian motion $W_t$ by $W^a_t=at+(1-t) W_{t/(1-t)}$. Thus, for any fixed $0\leq t\leq 1$, 
$$\mathbb{P}(W^a_t\geq 0)=\mathbb{P}\left( W_{t/(1-t)} \geq {-at\over 1-t}\right)={1\over 2}+{1\over 2}\mbox{erf}\left({a\over\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{t\over 1-t}\right).$$

The expected time that $W^a_t$ is positive will be the integral of this function over $0\leq t\leq 1$. I don't think it can be simplified.

Comment: @Roah No problem. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The integral suggested by Byron can be pushed around a little, leading to the expression
$$
1-{1\over 2} E[Z^2/(a^2+Z^2)]={1\over 2}+{1\over 2}E[a^2/(a^2+Z^2)]
$$
for the mean time spent above the $t$-axis by the pinned Wiener process.  Here $Z$ is a standard normal random variable.