# Simulation of pinned diffusion process

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Suppose I have a stochastic differential equation (in the Ito sense):
$$ dX_t = \mu(X_t)\,dt + \sigma(X_t)\, dW_t $$
in $\mathbb{R}^n$, where I know that $X_0=a$ and $X_T=b$. 
In other words, the process has been "pinned" at fixed times $0$ and $T$.

**I want to know how to simulate such an equation (i.e. produce trajectories numerically).**

I've seen some questions (
[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62958/considering-brownian-bridge-as-conditioned-brownian-motion), 
[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477928/is-the-density-of-probability-of-the-brownian-bridge-known), 
[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408620/brownian-bridge),
[4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35182/expected-sojourn-time-for-a-pinned-brownian-motion),
[5](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006101/what-is-the-distribution-of-the-area-between-a-brownian-bridge-and-the-x-axis)
)
on the "[Brownian Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge)", which is a special case of this.

Edit (081617): it appears that this process is also referred to as an [Ito bridge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/130926/are-ito-bridges-themselves-ito-processes) or as a [diffusion bridge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446189/reversing-a-diffusion-bridge). It turns out this is not as easy as I'd hoped. A promising paper (found with these better search terms) is *[Simulation of multivariate diffusion bridges](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.7728.pdf)*
by Bladt et al. Any help/suggestions are still appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried Euler Maruyama method to simulate it ?

Comment: @Khosrotash How can I apply Euler-Maruyama to a pinned diffusion?

Comment: Do you mean $$@ t=0 \to x(0)=a \\@t=T \to x(T)=b$$ and $a,b$ are assumed ?

Comment: @Khosrotash Yes indeed, all are fixed or known in advance.